# Можно ли опубликовать на сайте GUI программу на Python?

Tags: python, django, gui

Я встречал различные мини-игры онлайн, их туда как-то опубликовали.

У меня есть программа, написанная на Python и имеющая GUI интерфейс. Можно ли ее как-нибудь также опубликовать создав собственный сайт?

Может ли мне в этом помочь Django?

Comment: Если GUI не на HTML, то лучше не надо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так или иначе, **потребуется полное переписывание**.

> Можно ли ее как-нибудь также опубликовать создав собственный сайт?

**Нет (если под этим понимается возможность играть прямо в браузере)**. "GUI-интерфейс" в браузерах строится на веб-страницах. И только. Вы можете написать собственную логику управления HTML'ным GUI на JavaScript или другом языке, который компилируется в JavaScript.

Теоретически есть интерпретатор Python на JS, но вы не захотите его использовать для серьёзных задач. И даже если вы им вооружитесь, весь GUI вам  всё равно придётся переписывать заново, т. к. в браузерах совсем другие API.

> Может ли мне в этом помочь Django?

**Нет**. Django про серверную часть, код которой клиентская часть не выполняет сама, а лишь делает запросы к тому, кто действительно его выполняет: к серверу.

Запросы идут по некоторому протоколу передачи данных. Причём для полноценной замены взаимодействия с GUI протокол обмена между сервером и клиентом протокол должен быть **полнодуплексным**, т. е. поддерживать передачу по инициативе любой из сторон. **HTTP таковым не является.**

Таковым является, к примеру, WebSocket, с настройкой которого в Django, насколько мне известно, связаны определённые *приключения*. Хотя их можно преодолеть, а для некоторых игр полнодуплексный протокол даже не нужен... *есть немаленькая вероятность, что после убирания клиентского кода из вашей игры остаток всё равно придётся переписывать.*

---

Разумеется, всегда есть возможность просто опубликовать исходный код игры, который каждый может запустить у себя на машине вне браузера, но ввиду очевидности варианта я не стал его даже рассматривать.